# ImportError: No module named pyspark_llap

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-unittest

Below is my main code which I want to UnitTest
**get_data.py**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark_llap.sql.session import HiveWarehouseSession



def get_hive_data(query):
        hive_data = hive.executeQuery(query)
        return hive_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("HiveApp")\
        .getOrCreate()

    hive=HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()
    data = get_hive_data()
```

Below is my unittest code, I have written only the imports here, since i get error when i do **from get_data import /*/**
**test.py**

```
import unittest
import pyspark

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from get_data import *
```

ERROR
**ImportError: No module named pyspark_llap**

But if i run just get_data.py, it runs successfully
I am running it on edge node!